# Issue with displaying the text colors of the items inside QCombobox

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a QCombobox, consists of 3 or 4 items.
Whenever,I try to select an item from my QCombobox, the color of the item changes to black(is not at all visible clearly).When I move my cursor away from the Dialog UI, then the color of the item changes to white (and is now clearly visible).

I think the problem lies with my QCombobox focus, but still not sure if I need to take care of it while adding the items inside my QCombobox.

Can someone explain the method, so that text of the items inside my QCombobox are clearly visible always?

Comment: provide a [mcve], The problem for us is that you do not show the code and we can not see what part of the code generates the problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I wrote this line: MyComboBox->setFocusPolicy( Qt::NoFocus ); After including this line,it seems to work fine. But any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Look for any stylesheets added for the combobox.

Also you can look for "setItemdata" function and anything is done with respect colors (backgroundrole).

Or if it is tough to figure out and wasting time, after adding your combobox items, change the background color of items to your convenience (Red in below code is just an example).

```
ui->comboBox->addItems({"text1","text2","text3","text4"});

ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("QAbstractItemView { selection-background-color: red; }");
```